# VSC17 debugging nulls variables if edited in a foreach

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I've come across a minor issue (for this time) which is the following:

When I debug my code in Visual Studio Community 2017 and edit anything while it's inside a foreach, then all variables in that scope, including the variable being iterated, are set to null.

```
foreach (var bFile in baseCache) {
    var file = lastFolder + "\\" + bFile.Value.relPath;
    if (!lastCache.ContainsKey(file)) {
        if (file.Length > 255) { continue; }
        // TODO: do stuff when the file isn't present in the last backup
    }

    var lFile = lastCache[file];
    var comp = bFile.Value.compare(lFile);
    if (!comp.HasFlag(FileData.CompareFlags.CRC32 & FileData.CompareFlags.Size)) {

    }
}
```

In this part for example, I had a breakpoint at the 4th line, where it goes if "lastCache" doesn't contain the key that's represented by "file" at that time.

At that time there was just the continue; sitting at that spot and I changed it as it is shown now, and when I pressed F10 to step further because I wanted to verify this issue at that point, all variables shown in the snippet went 'null'.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how I can hopefully avoid this?

Currently this is just a minor bother when I'm changing things, but if this happens later in a bigger project it will be a real problem...

Edit: here's a link to the whole code, it's just a console app so luckily, that's easily done
https://www.pastiebin.com/5cf3e7dfa2985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of variables declared in the body of the loop is this very loop body. When you are entering the loop body they are not yet defined. E.g. `lFile` and `comp` will not have a value until the assignments have been executed.

If you want to preserve the value over several loops, then declare the variables before the loop.

---

A note to using dictionaries. it is more efficient to test the presence of a key and to get the value at once with `TryGetValue`

```
if (lastCache.TryGetValue(file, out string lFile)) {
    // do something with lFile.
} else {
    // file is missing
}
```

Comment: I understand if it'd had to reset the variables inside the scope of the loop, but the issue is that it also resets the variables in the scope above the loop.
As I said, the variable it's iterating through is also reset, for whatever reason.
It's been a while since I've used VS, last time was when it was still WS Express, not VS Community, but as I remember was this kind of editing back then not a problem.

Comment: We would have to see the whole relevant code to know what happens. E.g. class fields (variables at class level) are reset to `null` when you create an object with `new MyClass`.

Comment: I've added a link to the source, because what you mention sounds like a possible cause, but I'd be lying if I'd say that I fully understand what you meant with that.

Comment: Note that [Edit and Continue (Visual C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/edit-and-continue-visual-csharp?view=vs-2019) has its limitations. There are [Unsupported changes to code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/supported-code-changes-csharp?view=vs-2019#unsupported-changes-to-code).

Comment: That's helpful so thanks for that at this point, but I'm a little confused under which limitation my case falls.
At first I thought it was the iterator modification with a framework prior to .Net 4, but my program is targeted to 4.6.1, so that's not it, I think?

Comment: If you edit while debugging, i.e., manually change the code while the program is running, this falls under Edit and Continue. Then it is very well possible that the application does not behave as it would under normal circumstances. If you restart after having done edits, you should be able to debug and experience the normal behavior of C#.